# react native maps populate markers from array

Tags: for-loop, react-native, return

I am trying to render markers on the map dynamically with the end goal of markers being able to be created and destroyed at will while the application is running.   Everything is working fine, except for one small section which is this:

```
for (j = 0; j < markersArray.length; j ++) {
    console.log("Data: J=" + j + ", " + markersArray[j].key + ", " + markersArray[j].location[0] + ", " + markersArray[j].location[1] + ", " + markersArray[j].contactName);
    return <MapView.Marker
        key = { markersArray[j].key }
        coordinate = {{ 
            latitude: markersArray[j].location[0],
            longitude: markersArray[j].location[1] 
        }}
        title = { markersArray[j].contactName }
    />
}
```

The problem here is that the array has two or more objects inside it, but will only ever go through the loop once, where j = 0.   It never goes through the loop another time.  My thoughts are because the word "return" is used so that I can render the marker.   Is there a way around this?   All the data is perfect, it simply won't loop through more than the first time.

For the pedants among you who want the whole render function ;)   :

```
render() {
    return (
    <MapContainer>
        <MapView 
            style = { styles.map }
            region = { this.state.mapRegion }
            showsUserLocation = { true }
            followUserLocation = { true }
            onRegionChangeComplete = { this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this) }>
        <MapView.Circle
            key = { (this.state.currentLongitude + this.state.currentLongitude).toString() }
            center = { userPosition }
            radius = { RADIUS }
            strokeWidth = { 1 }
            strokeColor = { '#ffffff' }
            fillColor = { 'rgba(210,218,215,0.5)' }
            onRegionChangeComplete = { this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this) }
        />
        {(() => {
            console.log("Map Markers polling for data...");
            if (markersArray[0] != null) {
                console.log("Map Markers have found data");
                for (j = 0; j < markersArray.length; j ++) {
                    console.log("Data: J=" + j + ", " + markersArray[j].key + ", " + markersArray[j].location[0] + ", " + markersArray[j].location[1] + ", " + markersArray[j].contactName);
                    return <MapView.Marker
                        key = { markersArray[j].key }
                        coordinate = {{ 
                             latitude: markersArray[j].location[0],
                             longitude: markersArray[j].location[1] 
                        }}
                        title = { markersArray[j].contactName }
                     />
                }
            }
        })()}
        </MapView>
        <MessageBar />           
    </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: I have just tested removing the "return" from in front of <MapView.Marker and confirmed that the for loop now loops through properly.   But now it won't actually render the markers.   So is there a way of rendering them without the "return" keyword here?   Is there an alternate function that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function in order to render every object in that array.

> The `map(`) method creates a new array with the results of **calling a provided function on every element** in the calling array.

```
 {markersArray[0] != null && markersArray.map((marker, index) => (
            <MapView.Marker
                key = {index}
                coordinate = {{
                    latitude: marker.location[0],
                    longitude: marker.location[1]
                }}
                title = { marker.contactName }
            />
        ))
 }
```

Comment: I had been trying to get map() working for the past three house.... I pasted your code in and it works.   You beautiful man :D